# "too" after "so does" needed?

Tags: sentence-construction

When we say:

- When darkness comes, so does the cold.

Do we need to add "too" at the end?

P. S. Is it the same with other similar constructions?

- Where goes the duck, there go the ducklings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of *so...does...* **includes** 'too.' So, I feel that there's no need to repeat it. Or else, it'd look redundant.

On the other hand, I'd **never** alter any idiom. Let them be what and as they are! Idioms have their own styles and they are to be written as they are. If they don't have an article *then* no matter how *strongly* you feel to have the article, you shouldn't be putting it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the idiom is more:

“When darkness comes, so ***too*** does the cold.”

It sounds quaint, but if you’re going to invoke an idiom, you (usually) need to adhere to it.

And the second one is more like:

“Where the duck ***goes***, there go the ducklings.”